# I need to extract data from multiple columns in a worksheet and paste the columns in multiple worksheets in another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having problems with a code while extracting data from the source file. Can we use any function for extracting data from a range of worksheets to another workbook

Excel, VBA

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Borelog_(Nabinagar-Paturia Road) NSO.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Book1.xlsm")

y.Sheets("BR-26 (BH-2)").Range("M13:M37").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:A37")

x.Close SaveChanges:=False
y.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

The error I am getting is specific dimension not valid for current chart type

Answer (score 0):

This should Work:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Borelog_(Nabinagar-Paturia Road) NSO.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Book1.xlsm")


y.Sheets("BR-26 (BH-2)").Range("M13:M37").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:A37").Value

x.Close SaveChanges:=False
y.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Though I can't see why you are getting a `Chart Error`

---

New Answer:

```
Sub foo2()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Borelog_(Nabinagar-Paturia Road) NSO.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Book1.xlsm")

    For Each ws In y.Worksheets

        x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:A37").Copy
        ws.Range("M13:M37").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Next ws

    x.Close SaveChanges:=False
    y.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked for one sheet but is not working with multiple sheets

Comment: There are specific Ranges in the Code. You need to change the Sheet Name for that. Did you change the sheet name ??

Comment: @SamiulIslam . You can add the amended line in answer multiple times for different columns, just change the sheet name.

Comment: How can I copy and paste the same range values in all worksheets without changing the sheet name, because changing the sheet name seems to be a rigorous task when there are lot of sheets

Comment: So you want to paste the Same range on same cells in all the sheets of your `Workbook y` ?

Comment: yes so, how can I do that in a much simpler way, However there is an issue where the the values in different sheets in the source workbook has a link with the output sheets which is co-related. Can you share the code

Comment: I am getting run time error 9, Script out of range? How can I share the file

Comment: You can upload it to one drive or google Drive and share the link. on which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: Have a look at the link of two files where I want to input  the SPT values in the pile capacity excel sheet for each borehole automatically extracting from the borelog files

Comment: Sub foo2()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Borelog_(Nabinagar-Paturia Road) NSO.xlsx")
   Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SAMIUL\Desktop\VBA\Pile-capacity Nabinagar-Paturia.xls")

    For Each ws In y.Worksheets

        x.Sheets("BR26 BH02").Range("M13:M44").Copy
        ws.Range("G16:G47").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Next ws

    x.Close SaveChanges:=False
    y.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub